# Firestore server time unix java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to add unix time (eg 1589607025).

Currently, I am able to save the timestamp to firestore with FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

```
myObject.setTime(FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

How can i get the unixtime for FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in java so that i can save it to firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` returns a token value that get translated into a timestamp on the server.  If you want the value it wrote, you will have to read the document.  By that time, it will be off.

The SDK provides no method to simply get the server time.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions).

The [firebase/functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) repo contains a [time server](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server) example that uses an [https trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

I used this example to write my own `datetime` cloud function

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true })

exports.datetime =
  functions
    .https
    .onRequest((req, res) => cors(req, res, _ => res.json({ datetime: (new Date).toUTCString() })))
```